# Find device on personal hotspot network in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ip, hotspot

I need find IP of device which is connected on iPhones personal hotspot.

My solution is check every IP(from 172.20.10.2 to 172.20.10.255) which returns html with certain words.

Because device return html page on 80 now device has 172.20.10.7 IP on iPhones personal hotspot network.

iPhone IP is 172.20.10.1 (as gateway) on iOS 6.3 and IP getting started from 172.20.10.2 i think.

For my solution i need know: what is IP give personal hotspot on iOS7.

Can anybody help me with this?
I'm not have device with iOS7 only iOS6.3.
Just give me internal IP of device which connected with iOS7 personal hotspot device.

Comment: Try posting this question at apple.stackexchange.com - that is where all the iOS experts hang out...

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12614/getting-ip-address-of-hotspot-connection

Answer (score 2):

iOS 7 device hot spot gives an IP address in the 172.20.10.* range, just as for iOS 6

Comment: Thank you so much! How do you think whether there another solution for find IP on this network?

Comment: Are you running this on the device which is the source of the hotspot?

Comment: Yes. App run on iPhone with this personal hotspot.